# Code causes NullReferenceException only on iOS device

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

This code cause a null reference exception only on a iOS device. No idea how to debug it. XCode says that the null happens in this update method. More specifically in the if(tutorialdone). Any ideas ?

```
 void Update()
        {
            #region Stuff
            if (weNeedtoClickCrow == true)
            {
                Time.timeScale = 1;
                hand.SetActive(false);
                try
                {
                    coinBird.SetActive(true);
                    controller.paused = true;
                }
                catch (MissingReferenceException) { }
            }


            if (tutorialDone == true) 
            {
                DataHolder.holder.tutorialDone = true;
                StartCoroutine(ShowCompletionMessage());
                FadeTextUp(textToFade);
            }
            #endregion

            if (beginFade)
            {

                FadeTextDown(textToFade);

            }
        }
public IEnumerator ShowCompletionMessage()
    {
        textHeader.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Tutorial completed";
        textHeader.SetActive(true);

        textMsg.SetActive(false);
        yield return StartCoroutine(MyCouroutine.WaitForRealSeconds(3));
        Application.LoadLevel("Level1");

    }
```

Comment: What does `ShowCompletionMessage()` return? This is going to be next to impossible for us to debug with such a small snippet of code.

Comment: DataHolder.holder.tutorialDone = true; looks awfully suspect.  That said, there's no way to reproduce or identify the issue with what you've provided.

Comment: @David L its not the data holder. first thing I checked . @ Ron Beyer added the ShowCompletionMessage().

Comment: Null check every usage that could be null and throw a more informative exception when null is found. This will save you the guesswork

Comment: Also show the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that a `MissingReferenceException`turns into a `NullReferenceException` when unity builds for the iOS. Hence my try/catch was not working.